# How can I navigate deeper in XML and append data in it

Tags: c#, append, xmldocument, selectnodes

I have loaded XmlDocument into memory and created new XmlElement. Now I am trying to add XmlElement to the path /report/section/hosts but I don't know how. I can add it easily below root node of XML but I cannot figure out how can I navigate deeper level in XML and just append there. In pseudo I am trying to do this:

*doc.SelectNodes("/report/section/hosts").AppendChild(subRoot);*

The code:

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        doc.Load("c:\\data.xml");

        //host
        XmlElement subRoot = doc.CreateElement("host");

        //Name
        XmlElement ElName = doc.CreateElement("name");
        XmlText TxtName = doc.CreateTextNode("text text");
        ElName.AppendChild(TxtName);
        subRoot.AppendChild(ElName);
        doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(subRoot);

        doc.Save("c:\\data.xml");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try SelectSingleNode instead of SelectNodes

```
XmlElement parent = (XmlElement)doc.SelectSingleNode("/report/section/hosts")
parent.AppendChild(subRoot);
```

Answer (score 1):

The SelectNodes method returns a list of Nodes.
You should use SelectSingleNode instead...

e.g. (top of my head, did not test in Visual Studio)

```
doc.SelectSingleNode("/report/section/hosts").AppendChild(subRoot);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there.  Try using SelectSingleNode instead:

```
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/report/section/hosts");
node.AppendChild(subRoot);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a reference to an XmlElement in your doc (other than the root) to append to. There are [a number of methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument_methods.aspx) available on XmlDocument such as `GetElementById` and `SelectSingleNode` which do this for you in different ways, research to taste.

That said, the whole API in this area is generally regarded as a bit painful, do you have LINQ available?